# Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?

Tags: release-management

I'm following the [upgrade instructions on Ubuntu's website](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer), but on launching the upgrade tool I get this response:

```
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Strangely, it is also possible to get this message when there is no internet connection, e.g. when networking is down. For some reason no error message is shown in such cases.

Comment: I had previously followed the instructions titled "Disable Automatic Updates from Graphical User Interface" on the page https://linuxconfig.org/disable-automatic-updates-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux to disable automatic checks for updates. With that change in place, `do-release-upgrade` returns "No new release found". I had to undo this change to get it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the "Final Release" a "Development Release"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229890/is-the-final-release-a-development-release)

Answer (score 268):

According to Ubuntu Engineering Foundations team manager Steve Langasek:

> Upgrades between LTS releases are not enabled by default until the first point release, 14.04.1, scheduled for July.  It is recommended that most LTS users wait until then before upgrading to 14.04.

If you choose to upgrade before then, you can pass the `-d` option to the upgrade tool, running `do-release-upgrade -d` or `update-manager -d`, to upgrade from vanilla 12.04 to 14.04. (`-d` stands for devel.)

This question explains the justification for waiting for the prompt:

- [Upgrading LTS to LTS (server) -- why wait for the first point release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125825/upgrading-lts-to-lts-server-why-wait-for-the-first-point-release)

Comment: @jorge-castro that makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: Why, then, is do-release-upgrade (without the -d) still saying "No new release found" a few days after the .1 has been released in iso form?  (My /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades says "Prompt=lts")

Comment: From an inspection of the code, it seems that "normal" releases default to a URL http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release which lists 14.04, and LTS releases use the URL http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts which doesn't list it at all.  I think they haven't updated the meta information yet.

Comment: That seems like a release oversight, can you file a bug and CC me? email is in my profile, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro Is this indeed a release oversight, and is there any idea when it will be fixe? Was a bug filed, and where can I follow it?  (I searched, but could not find it.  I also want to switch from 12.04 LTS to 14.04.1 LTS, and I just want to do it through the Update Manager.)

Comment: Looks like [changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) is fixed now.

Comment: @DLosc Yes, and I now get offered the upgrade to '14.04.1 LTS' in the Update Manager GUI.  Thanks to <whoever>!

Comment: This can also be used to upgrade from non-LTS releases if `do-upgrade-release` doesn't indicate new candidates. Just used `-d` to upgrade from 15.10 to current.

Comment: Echoing @tudor, the same seems to be true for 16.04.1. The x.x.1 release was 5 days ago, but the [LTS releases](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) do not list it. The only thing I have found about this is [the mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2016-July/000209.html) which says "soon."

Comment: For me (14.04 LTS), `do-release-upgrade` works for me.

Comment: Eight years after this question was asked, the problem still exists. I'm running Xubuntu 18.04, have my update preference set to lts in file `etc/update-manager/release-upgrade`, and Xubuntu 20.04.1 has been released. Yet, `do-release-upgrade` does not offer to upgrade to 20.04.1, perhaps because https://changelogs.xubuntu.com/meta-release-lts does not list the new release.

Comment: Its 21.04 release and the problem still exists. I can't see the updated meta at https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release

Comment: The year is 2023 and the problem persists. It's been 15 days since 23.10 has been released and http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release is yet to be updated. How can I report this to Canonical?

Answer (score 110):

If one has no access to a GUI and wants the update on terminal:

1. Edit the file

   ```
   /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
   ```

   for `Prompt` to match either `normal` or `lts`. (See list below what fits your case, be aware that you can only upgrade an LTS to another LTS version):

   ```
   [DEFAULT]
   Prompt=normal
   ```
2. Test correct version is found, run

   ```
   do-release-upgrade -c
   ```
3. Upgrade in case correct version is shown:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

   If you want to upgrade to development state (e.g. if you want to go from 18.10 to 19.04 before its official release) the `-d` flag is helpful:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade -d
   ```

---

That way I could upgrade a 12.04 to 12.10.

The available `Prompt` options are:

> - never  - Never check for a new release.
> - normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade
>     to the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
>     release.
> - lts - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after the
>     currently-running one. Note that this option should not be used if the
>     currently-running release is not itself an LTS release, since in that
>     case the upgrader won't be able to determine if a newer release is
>     available.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I simply changed from Prompt=normal to Prompt=lts and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: I found the opposite problem to what Florin describes.  On 4-21-18, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS was saying 'No new release found' until I changed from 'Prompt=lts' to 'Prompt=normal'.   It picked 16.04 LTS to upgrade to, which is what I wanted.  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Notice the -d at the end; from the `man` page:

```
  -d, --devel-release
      If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the development release
```

This works even with `Prompt=lts` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.

Comment: the same as was described in the question...

Answer (score 5):

In case you are having this issue and it's not the 18.04.1 problem or and switching to lts or non-lts updates changes nothing, try the following (super hard to find steps).

Open a terminal and type: `export DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=true` before the `do-release-upgrade -c` command to see what goes wrong.

If you are getting the same problem I have you would see:

```
result of meta-release download: '<urlopen error timed out>'
NO self.metarelease_information
No new release found.
```

You could be facing the issue that you have a proxy configured for apt that is no longer relevant. Because of historic reasons ([bug #446552](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/446552)), there are several unreasonable places where the updater will look for proxy settings. Beside the system-wide settings you should also check bash environment variables, `gconf` gnome proxy settings, `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and in my case `/root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf`.

The latter mind you no longer has a working menu in the GUI and the only way to remove the proxy settings is to edit the file. You can also just remove the file, that also works.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for. I was deciding to go through a python debugging session but you saved me! I had a proxy configured in /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf and I could not understand who or what set it there!

Answer (score 3):

2 options :

1. Burn the iso and put it in your drive, it will detect the upgrade automatically
2. Go in you synaptics options, then Preference > distribution > Always prefer the highest version.

Problem solved ?

Comment: 10.04 releases won't upgrade right away, see the link I posted above.