# 12.04 LiveUSB doesn't upgrade for 10.04 installation?

Tags: upgrade, 12.04, live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No new release found” when upgrading a server from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-a-server-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts)

I burnt Ubuntu to USB and when I try to install it, it doesn't allow me to upgrade to 12.04, it allows just to install it alongside. Why?