# What are the advantages of 12.04.4?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

What advantages does Ubuntu 12.04.4 offers ?

Comment: See the related question [Upgrading LTS to LTS (server) — why wait for the first point release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/125825/70254)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 12.04 works for them, and 14.04 is still new and has the usual "early adopter" bugs.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was voted down - I agree with @fkraiem about the "early adopters" (I am one) and also found that my other computer needed to move back from 14.04 to 12.04 because of compatability issues.