# Trouble when opening laptop lid. Only black screen is displayed. Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, laptop, suspend, asus

I have a Asus S56CA laptop. When I bought this laptop, it came prinestalled with Windows 8 wich I updated to 8.1. I soon decided that Windows wasn't right for me and decided to use my old Ubuntu 12.04 LTS disk to install Ubuntu and experienced no problems with this. I then updated this to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using `sudo update-manager -d`.

After this update I have had troubles waking up my laptop after closing the lid. I am either receiving a black, blank screen where all I can see is the mouse (The mouse can be moved) or the lock screen which I cannot interact with at all (Entering Password, moving mouse etc). I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem and how they got around it. If not, does anyone know a way to fix this and stop it from happening in the future.

Thanks all.

EDIT:
**sudo fdisk -l:**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes    
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00035215

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   968617983   484307968   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       968620030   976771071     4075521    5  Extended
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5       968620032   976771071     4075520   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

**df -h:**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       455G   14G  418G   4% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           393M  1.2M  392M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  580K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please help us help you by providing more information. I could be more helpful if I had the output of `df -h` and `sudo fdisk -l` for example. This appears to be a hibernation problem. Having the details of the disks in use and their mount locations will be helpful to us.

Comment: Also I think you may have been intending on `update-manager --dist-upgrade` instead of `update-manager -d`

Comment: Please edit and add the information to your question. There isn't enough room in the comments

Comment: Have now added said info to question.

Comment: I do not think that `df` or `fdisk` info is needed for this problem --- seems a clear problem of graphic drivers. Try to see if this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/436389/16395 helps you.

Comment: @ElderGeek --- your comment about `update-manager` is wrong, the OP is right. You need `-d` to upgrade from a LTS to a LTS before it reaches `.1` release. Moreover, normally hibernation is disabled, so the problem is much more probably a suspend problem, and related to the graphic driver at it.

Comment: @Rmano I read through the question link that you posted and was unable to resume suspend from the virtual boot. I tried looking at the FAIL secton but it gave:
bash: /var/log/pm-suspend.log: Permission denied

Comment: @Rmano thank you for clarifying. I must have misunderstood the man page. I'll review it again. Hmm. `-d, --devel-release
              Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible`

Comment: @ElderGeek I do not understand the code you want me to input, can you clarify?

Comment: that was a response to Rmano.

Comment: Sorry, misread. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: @ElderGeek on `update-manager`, check http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next and http://askubuntu.com/questions/125825/upgrading-lts-to-lts-server-why-wait-for-the-first-point-release

Comment: @Rmano as I commented before, I went to the fail section (I could not resume from the virtual console) but when '/var/log/pm-suspend.log' is entered I receive: 'bash: /var/log/pm-suspend.log: Permission denied'

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem.. sudo or chmod anyone?

Comment: try `sudo cat /var/log/pm-suspend.log` (Full disclosure: I do not own a laptop now or in the future)

Comment: @ElderGeek found something that works, but I am unable to find it again. I'll include the solution in the question asap

Answer (score 1):

This can be a temp. fix by trying to avoid suspending. Do the following: Go to `Dash` then `System Setting`, `power` and the choose `When lid is closed do nothing`.

Comment: Thanks. I have set this and it appears to working okay now. I looked at the error that is displayed and it mentioned something about Kernel oops. I don't know what this means but maybe this could help?

Comment: More than likely. The exact error message is always helpful.