# Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS to 14.04.1 LTS upgrade: "no new release found"

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, server, upgrade, lts

According to [Trusty Tahr Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule), Ubuntu LTS 14.04.1 (first .1 version) was released two days ago.
Unfortunately when trying to upgrade using the `do-release-upgrade` command I get the message `No new release found`.

Command line output:

```
root@foobar:~# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
root@foobar:~# do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

The threads [upgrading LTS to LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125825/upgrading-lts-to-lts-server-why-wait-for-the-first-point-release) and no [new release found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next) make totally sense, but as I understand the first dot 1 version of Ubuntu 14.04 (14.04.1) has yet been released, so why can't I still upgrade LTS to LTS?

Is there a way to upgrade properly, **not** using the -d option with the `do-release-upgrade` command?

Comment: According to the release instruction: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-July/000188.html *Users of Ubuntu 12.04 will soon be offered an automatic upgrade to 14.04.1 via Update Manager*

Comment: I have the same issue. @Chel I saw that too in my research, but the question is, when is "soon"?

Comment: @Dis Who knows? It may be a chance thing, whereby only 10% of people requesting get it otherwise the download would be painful with all the requests at the same time. (Purely speculation)

Comment: @Tim *somebody* must know!

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next/125492#125492

Comment: @Dis Not if, as I said, it is random...

Comment: @Tim I meant if it was random like you said, someone must know that it's random. That's a valid answer if it is the case.

Comment: I haven't found any evidence to support that it is random... It says you should be able to upgrade from the 24th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually -p option works to run the release upgrade:

```
do-release-upgrade -p
```

Here is the explanation of the -p option:

```
-p, --proposed
Try upgrading to the latest release using the upgrader from Ubuntu-proposed
```

P.S. Also on #ubuntu IRC channel nobody seems to know what actually "triggers" the `do-release-upgrade` command to work properly...

P.P.S. Caution when upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04.1 LTS, as [grub will fail to update kernel list](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2222709).

Comment: Nope, `Checking for a new Ubuntu release /n
No new release found` Didn't work for me

Comment: According to answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49691/what-is-the-proposed-repository), the Proposed repository can be unstable and isn't usually suitable for production systems. Even if  `-p` does perform the upgrade (as it does for me), I doubt that it is "a way to upgrade properly," any more than `-d` is.