# No 12.04 upgrade choice from 10.04

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No new release found” when upgrading a from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-a-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts)

On both my laptops (running 10.04), all the latest updates are installed, in the settings "Long Term Support Releases Only" is ticked, and yet the proposition to upgrade to 12.04 never shows up.

I've also tried with "do-release-upgrade" from the cli, which gives me:
"
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
"

What's going on?

Should I upgrade through the liveCD, or is there anything I've forgotten?

Comment: Oh yes, it looks like a duplicate of this one, thanks.