# My install of 10.04 does not show that there is an LTS upgrade available, what do I do?

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, 12.04, lts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“No new release found” when upgrading a from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-a-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts)

This is an install on an older machine I have for my grandmother. I installed 10.04 quite some time ago and would now like to upgrade her to something newer, but for some reason, even after checking, rechecking, and checking again, there is no Upgrade to 12.04 button available in Update Manager. And I really don't want to do a clean install, as I don't want to lose all of her settings and documents. So any help?