# How to upgrade from 10.04 to higher version without CD and USB stick

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, upgrade, internet

I want to upgrade from ubuntu 10.04 to a higher version. My optical disk drive is not working neither my system is USB bootable. I do not want to install wubi in windows as my system is dual bootable, both OS intalled parallely and i want to keep it as it is.
please suggest me the option to upgarde using internet.
Lat time i upgraded from 9.10 through update manager but this time i can't find an option to do so.
waitning for ur suggestions. thank u.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts

Answer (score 0):

1. go to `System` **-** `Preferences` **-** `update manager`
2. hit the check button
3. choose upgrade to 12.04. It should appear above the updates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cd or any external device to do an upgrading.

Just go to

```
System - Preferences - Update Manager
```

Make sure you have `upgrading to a newer version` on.
You can chage it in the

```
upgrade manger options menu.
```

You should see this(more or less):

[image]