# upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 - No upgrade option available in update manager

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

Update manger do not provide option to upgrade. It displays "Your system is up-to-date" instead. I tried Check button many times but received same message. Please help.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts

Comment: @Uri: that question is more specific to 'LTS to LTS' upgrades.

Comment: @david6 The answer applies here too.

Answer (score 6):

**NOTE:** Specific to upgrade of **11.10** to **12.04** (and not from **10.04 LTS**)

From: [ubuntu.com - UbuntuDesktop - Upgrading](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop)  - ***GUI method***

**Upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10**

To upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 on a desktop system, start "Update Manager". It should display the following message: "New distribution release '12.04' is available. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions".

***I can confirm this works on my Ubuntu 11.10 desktop.***

**OR**

From: [ubuntu.com - UbuntuServer - Upgrading](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuServer)  - ***command-line method***

**Upgrade**

**From 11.10 to 12.04**

To upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 on a server system, follow the steps listed below:

Install the update-manager-core package (if it is not already installed).

Run **sudo do-release-upgrade** to launch the upgrade tool. Follow the on-screen instructions.
  Note that the server upgrade is now more robust and will utilize GNU screen and automatically re-attach in case of dropped connection problems, for example.

***So, type the following commands:***

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

sudo do-release-upgrade

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: The image is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do an apt-get purge update-manager-core and the install update-manager-core before do-release-upgrade would recognize any new releases for 11.10.