# Upgrade to 12.10 from 12.04 not available in update manager

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, update-manager, 12.10

My update manager does not give me the option to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10. That is, the "New distribution release '12.10' is available. Click Upgrade and follow the on-screen instructions" section is not shown.

I had the same problem upgrading to 12.04. Spent hours trying to upgrade the system, got lucky somehow, don’t definitively know how.

What I have done,

- used Synaptic to clear package cache.
- reloaded package list and upgraded all packages.
- checked that ubuntu-standard and ubuntu-desktop packages are
  installed.
- checked that the "notify me of new version" setting in update-manager is set to "all new versions"
- update manager reports there are "no new updates"
- `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` reports no release available
- running `update-manager -d` does not help.
- `cat /etc/lsb-release` output is: `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04 DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS`

[Similar problem 1 |](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202707/my-update-manager-wont-upgrade-to-12-10-from-12-04) 
[Similar problem 2 |](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136148/upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04-no-upgrade-option-available-in-update-manager) 
[Similar problem 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202695/no-facility-exists-in-update-manager-12-04-to-upgrade-to-12-10-why)

Comment: Terminal>`update-manager -d`, an Update Manager window will open, in the upper part it will say that a new Version of Ubuntu is available.

Comment: As noted in question, i've tried that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to upgrade my system by downloading the Ubuntu 12.10 desktop iso image, writing it to DVD and booting from it. The installation utility has an option to upgrade the current installation rather than reinstalling a complete new system.

I did not lose my home-folder data, however, I lost all other system configurations and had to reinstall all non-default apps. I suggest making backups before installing.

Answer (score 6):

Open "Update Manager" > click on "Setting" (bottom left) > change "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" from "for long term support version" to "for any new version" > close

the again "check" for updates.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, bullet point four points out that I did try that already. `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` reports `prompt=normal` also.

Comment: oh, one another option! you can download Ubuntu 12.10 iso from website and boot it, then in installation menu select upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10.

Comment: Was able to upgrade my system by booting from the 12.10 CD. I did not lose my home-folder, however, I lost all other system configurations and had to reinstall all non-default apps.