# need help upgrading from 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is “No new release found” when upgrading 10.04 to 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts)

i have ubuntu 10.04 and want to upgrade to the next lts version = 12.04.  Is it best to upgrade thru successive versions ie. 10.10, 11.04, 11.10, then 12.04 OR straight to 12.04.  When i go to upgrade it does not give me the option to go to 12.04 even with LTS versions selected.

So, to upgrade directly to 12.04 do i have to do a "new" install from a cd (which i have) ?

cannot find an answer to this question on the help sites.

thanks for any help.