# Can't upgrade ubuntu server from 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, lts, release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my 10.04 server using do-release-upgrade, but it keeps saying there is no new version available.

If I change the `prompt` config in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` to `normal`, I am able to upgrade to 10.10 though, but I don't want to perform 4 separate upgrades in order to reach the new lts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To upgrade Ubuntu 10.04 server to 12.04

First make sure that you have the latest updates

```
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Install update-manager-core

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

Edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=lts`

Launch the upgrade tool, and follow the on-screen instructions:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

<sup>Source: [http://library.linode.com](http://library.linode.com/upgrading/upgrade-to-ubuntu-12.04-precise?format=print)</sup>

Comment: See [same question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts)

Comment: Even though the release was already out, I still had to pass the "-d" parameter, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Install update-manager-core .

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=lts`

then do as do-release-upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Install update manager core

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

and launch upgrade manager using

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Follow the on screen instructions