# Root Server - nothing works after Ubuntu 10.04 Update to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, server, 10.04

Yesterday i tried to update my root server (Ubuntu 10.04 with Plesk 11.5) with the accepted answer of this treath: [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154223/cant-upgrade-ubuntu-server-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts) Unfortunately i interrupted the Putty Process :( and insert the same commands again. the precoess runs through... In Plesk the Ubuntu Version don´t change and my server runs fine.

Then i decided (i dont know why) to make a update with

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

everything works fine.

Then i changed my Server memory in the php.ini file.

everything works fine.

Afterwards i run this command with Putty:

reboot

Looks fine - but a few minutes later all my sites (4 Domains) dont work anymore. Also the connection with Putty is not possible! I cant connect per FTP to my server or something else...??? No way.

I asked my server provider for help, but they have no technical person for the weekend and i should wait until monday. In my server backend from my server provider i can access a limited server panel where i can start, restart, stop (regular), stop (soft) and stop (hard) my server.

I tried to stop (regular) and start the server - no change I tried to restart the server - no change

In this Panel i also see the server status. It shows me "running" but under the configuration there is additional info like:

"no image included" "no Baremetal Tools" Distribution: "Ubuntu"

There is also a memory and Cpu display - both shows 0 load

Any Idea to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually those VPS providers only support certain versions of your OS with Plesk, etc. I run into exactly the same problem as you some time ago.
After upgrading from the command line nothing worked and reading through the support documents I found out that the version I wanted to use was not supported and I had to go back to a backed up version.

Ubuntu opens a backup shell though on port 1022. You might be able to connect to this shell if you haven't rebooted your server yet. If you are extremly lucky you may find a way to recover or downgrade - otherwise going back to a back up is a safe approach.

Comment: Thx for your tips. Can you provide me some help to open the port and downgrade the package? i have a server backup in my external backupRepository with 17GB from yesterday - but my last snapshot with over 400Gb ist 4 Month old. A dwongrade back would be awesome. best