# Switch from normal to LTS release

Tags: 12.04, lts

We started with an Ubuntu 11.10 for a server system. The upgrade to 12.04 went smoothly. Now I only want to upgrade to the next LTS release. However, the system keeps telling me that 12.10 is available. Although this is true, I want to stick to LTS from now on.

How do I switch the release-"mode"?

I want the system to act like I installed it from an LTS-image.

**UPDATE**

After logging into the system I am greeted by

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-63-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
New release '12.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

The file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` has `Prompt=lts` configured.

Comment: If its a server, you have not installed ubuntu-desktop and you don't have a GUI, right?

Comment: Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/154223/cant-upgrade-ubuntu-server-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts

Comment: @mikewhatever: The answer might be the same, but the questions is different in sense, so it can't be a duplicate of that.

Comment: @jobin Why waste keystrokes? Got a better answer? Post it!

Comment: @Jobin correct, there is no X installed.

Comment: @mikewhatever I'm gonna try the answer you linked to. As I am looking for this a long time already, I don't consider this a duplicate (in question). I'll see about the answer.

Comment: Why don't you try booting from the Ubuntu Server 14.04 installation disc (or flash drive) and let the installer do it?

Comment: It's our main database server, @FuzzyToothpaste, so rebooting just to get rid of one line of text only I see is a little over the top ;-) . It's not blocker, but something I really want to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I was reading [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/110483/20054), and it had this:

> Upgrades between LTS releases are not enabled by default until the
>   first point release, 12.04.1/14.04.1, scheduled for July/August. It is
>   recommended that most LTS users wait until then before upgrading to
>   12.04/14.04.

Ubuntu 14.04.1 is scheduled for July 24th.

Hope that explains why you don't get the 14.04 prompt.

PS: As you guys don't seem to like my duplicate suggestions, I humbly concede, and post this as a possible answer.

Comment: I'll wait until the release of 14.04.1 and see what happens then. I am a little confused why it's offering me the upgrade to `12.10`, though…

Comment: After the release of 12.04.5, I get a hint to update to 14.04.1. Thanks for the explanation.