# Problem upgrading from 10.04 LTS to 12.04.1 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade, lts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is “No new release found” when upgrading 10.04 to 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts)

Ubuntu 12.04.1 was released yesterday and I still can't update from 10.04

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts