# unable to see 12.04 upgrade listed in Update manager

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is “No new release found” when upgrading 10.04 to 12.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts)

i am not seeing 12.04 LTS available for update in Update Manager. i followed the update instructions, and set to lts release only. when on normal release, i see only 10.10. i wish to upgrade to 12.04 LTS.

what am i missing?

my data is backed up, but i have at least 2 yrs of programs installed and i would not like to lose all those programs and configs for various services and such. otherwise i would do a clean install.

suggestions? or more specific instructions please.

thanks. pete

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running at this time?

Comment: 10.04 LTS currently.

Comment: um... why did you close? there is no exact duplicate... i did the update path from 10.04 > 10.10 > 11.04 > and as you may have guessed by now, THERE IS NO UPGRADE PATH TO 12.04 LTS - per all your instructions, sudo cmd's ecterra... bottom line, something is janked up in the apt or update configs and is a bug of sorts. reopen this ticket. also, if you can post the example of exactness, i would enjoy taking at look at. remember, i followed your instructions, and no 12.04 LTS ever shows up. i'll be awaiting your responses... thanks, oly

Comment: further more i am currently at 11.04 and im already see degradation in simple functions, like bash not tab completing properly... help!

Comment: what worked for someone else, obviously isnt working for me... keep that in mind ...

Comment: looking at link now... ill let you know if i find anything interesting to try... brb

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts?lq=1welp, there is nothing in that link that worked, i just tried, whats next?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have a  Backup of everything you absolutely can't afford to lose.

Then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then see if you have the option to upgrade to 12.04.  If not then

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

Update: if the above gives you trouble, try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install update-manager-core

do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: after doing the above, it states 10.10, not 12.04 LTS. What am i missing? thanks

Comment: awaiting the next step, do-release-upgrade -d did not set to 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Try `update-manager -d`

Comment: nope, still no 12.04 LTS option,,, ponders why it was closed. becuz i didn't do it fast enough? that's really bad support to close a ticket without resolution or feedback from the last cmd avised to execute..... sighs...