# Upgrading from LTS to LTS

Tags: upgrade

I am running linux 10.04 (lucid) on my laptop. My update manager does not show upgrade to 12.04 option. I have checked all the settings as posted in previous queries (changing options is update manager) using -d in update etc. But still I am unable to resolve it. I access internet using a proxy I hope that does not matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading 10.04 to 12.04 LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts)

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Answer (score 2):

***How many of these steps have you followed?***

From: [wiki.ubuntu.com > Upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_to_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS)

> To upgrade from 10.04 LTS on a desktop system before then, upgrade over the network with the following procedure.
>
> 1. Start System/Administration/Software Sources
> 2. On the Updates tab, set Show new distribution releases: to Long term support releases only, then press Close.
> 3. Press Alt-F2 and type update-manager -d
>
>    1. Click the Check button to check for new updates. If there are any updates to install, use the Install Updates button to install them, and press Check again after that is complete.
>    2. A message will appear informing you of the availability of the new release. Click Upgrade. 
>         Follow the on-screen instructions.

*For best results, you should be fully updated (to **10.04.4**) before starting.*

Answer (score 0):

open your update manager and click at settings and then change the following settings to Long Term Releases in the marked menu .

[image]