# Error trying to upgrade from 10.04.4 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, dist-upgrade

Today i wanted to upgrade to 12.04 and I checked my update manager. But it it not showing the upgrade option. How can i upgrade? im using 10.04.4

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade via the Software Center? (Did that even exist in 10.04?).

Comment: @Mochan software center dosent show the option to upgrade :(

Comment: Duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-10-04-to-12-04-lts

Comment: @isuru-buddhika, have you gone into the Software Sources and enabled upgrading distros? If not, you can follow the steps in [this tutorial](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-12-04-to-ubuntu-12-10). The instructions are basic, quick and easy. Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 1):

Check by using this command:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: i tried ir now. But no help :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried `sudo update-manager -d` and got it