# Precise to Trusty Upgrade? No Notification so far

Tags: update-manager, release-management

I checked the settings of my update manager (cf picture below), but I have received no notification so far for Trusty, I was wondering if this was normal, or if I would have to install it manually?

**EDIT** If I change my settings to "Any new version" I get a notification for 12.10. I don't really want to run four upgrades to get to the current version though...

**EDIT 2** [This link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04) is very useful to understand the upgrade on Ubuntu. The answer is basically that there won't be any notification until the first point release (14.04.1), but users who wish to bypass this and install the new LTS without having to wait can run `sudo update-manager -d`. Remember to backup your system beforehand to protect your data against screwups.

[image]

Comment: It's here now...

Comment: I ended up installing it on another partition (using the same home) a few weeks ago :) But thanks for the update!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you'll get it [until the first point release](https://askubuntu.com/a/125492/38585), and it's probably worth waiting for LTS to LTS upgrades.

Comment: DV ... why? The information is (AFAIK) correct and sufficient.

Comment: You did answer the question: +1 for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I don't know who downvoted, but your answer is the most useful, I think I might wait until the next first point release then.

Comment: I did not downvote. The downvote could also be because this really is a duplicate and more experienced users might think that answering duplicate questions is a way to get rep easily without doing research. No offense to you David, you answered the question well.

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo update-manager -d` from command line

Comment: Thanks for this, but I think I'll wait until the first point release as suggested by @David.