# 12.04 No new release found for upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, software-sources

when i log into my server, I see the following message

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-15-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

New release '12.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

But then when I run `sudo do-release-upgrade` i get this message:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Doesn't that seem kinda silly?  I was thinking that I should upgrade to version 13.04 or even 14.04 to be more up-to-date, but like this I am kinda stuck.

I have seen this post: [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next)

But that was answered back in 2012, I would think that the new version is available for upgrade now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As per this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next stated since 12.04 is a LTS release:

Upgrades between LTS releases are not enabled by default until the first point release, 14.04.1, scheduled for July. It is recommended that most LTS users wait until then before upgrading to 14.04.

You can used the -d option to the upgrade tool, running **do-release-upgrade** -d or **update-manager -d**, to upgrade from vanilla 12.04 to 14.04. (-d stand for devel)

As per this article: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/05/17/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-end-of-life-reached-on-may-16-2014/ Ubuntu 12.10 reached End of life on 16 May this year.