# Upgrading current version of Ubuntu, on a multi boot system.

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I find that I'm unable to upgrade the existing version of Ubuntu on my multiboot system (Windows 7 on the other half of the partition). Can I simply do a clean install from within the partition?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next

Answer (score 0):

You can do a clean install, but you can also try the following command in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following in a Terminal :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```