# Ubuntu 12.04 does not automatically upgrade to 14.04. Why?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

This maybe a silly Question but it has racked my brain.

My friend in college has received an upgrade for 14.04 on his Ubuntu 13.04. Why don't I get the same update on my 12.04?

I have downloaded the ISO of 14.04 but then I would have to redo everything that I did in 12.04 again.

One another I have in mind : Is 14.04 better than 12.04? Is it worth replacing 12.04? Should I do it if I am never gonna get an auto upgrade?

I have been using 12.04 and I like it. But I'm always into trying new updated stuff. I'm in a dilemma.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you ask why you have not been prompted to upgrade. At first hand it depends on your settings.

Start `software-properties-gtk` and select the *Updates* tab. At the bottom you find the label "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version", and that's the one. If you have the "For long-term support versions" selected, you will be [notified only after the 14.04.1 release](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04). If you change it to "For any new version", you should be notified instantly about the possibility to upgrade to 14.04.

Another option is to run

```
update-manager -c
```

from a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

'sudo update-manager -d'
This command automatically update your 12.04 to 14.04, and it don't touch your files and sets. Also, if you have downloaded ISO, start upgrade your system by it. When you start upgrading, there will be an option like "Keep everything same, just upgrade system.", so you can choose this option.

Comment: Why the `-d` option? Did you mean `-c`?

Comment: Actually, I don't know differences of -d and -c. You can get information writing "man update-manager".  I just do it with -d. :)

Comment: I see it suggested quite often. Then I checked the man page, and it's pretty clear about the difference. So I thought it's time to start doing The Right Thing. ;)