# Am I too late to upgrade a 14.04 to 14.10?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

Am I too late to upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 now? (2015/08/29)

When I the command to do the upgrade, it tells me that it cannot find any new releases:

```
ubuntu$ do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

I changed the type of upgrade from lts to normal, but that did not help. That is, the very first time I ran do-release-upgrade, it told me that 14.10 would be next...

```
do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '14.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Next I tried to run do-release-upgrade without the -c and the message saying that no new release available appeared.

Would I have to download a 14.10 ISO so I can upgrade to 15.04 (which is the goal here)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next)

Comment: This is because you are running an LTS version. Just for the record, 14.10 is obsolete by now.

Comment: @Lucio, I already changed the prompt to normal, no luck. I'm afraid that "obsolete" means I cannot simply upgrade to 15.04 now... which rather sucks.

Comment: What is the output for `do-release-upgrade -d`? You can always upgrade using other methods.

Comment: Ah! Darn! That works. I guess the developer version remains accessible whereas the official one being obsolete is not responding. That being said, the -c command should properly react to that possibility, I think. It is going now, we'll see what happens. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexisWilke `-c` flag reacts to LTS releases. The `-d` flag specifies that you can upgrade to development releases. Keep in mind, that development releases *might* have bugs and as of `15.04` Ubuntu is switching to `systemd`, different init system for services.

Comment: @Lucio, In regard to this question being a duplicate, the problem is different: in the link you proposed, the user wants to be on the edge before it "exists" (is available for download). In my case, I'm late and that was not really answered in that other post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) -- Instructions for skipping over 14.10 and upgrading directly to 15.04 instead.

Answer (score 2):

As Lucio mentioned in a comment, you can always upgrade to a development version. That way I could first upgrade to 14.10 and then to 15.04.

This is done using the `do-release-upgrade -d` command to go from 14.04 to 14.10 (the `-d` is required because the official version is obsolete so only the developer version is available for upgrade.)

Once 14.10 was upgraded, I could upgrade to 15.04 in the normal way, that is, using the `do-release-upgrade` without the `-d` option.

So if **you are late** upgrading from an LTS or other version to a newer version, you may need to use the `-d` to go to an intermediate version considered obsolete.