# Can't upgrade to 16.04 LTS from 15.10

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

So I'm attempting to upgrade to 16.04 LTS on my 15.10 machine and it doesn't seem to recognize that the upgrade is available. Are there any suggestions where to start investigating this issue? So far nothing has indicated where I might start looking to solve this.

The result of sudo do-release-upgrade -cd is:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Comment: Is this kind of upgrade the same as for LTS to LTS? In which case you would need to wait a couple more months for the [first  point release](http://askubuntu.com/a/125492/38585) (that post also has some instructions for circumventing this).

Comment: In theory they -d should set it too use the 'Development' Release which should be available. Which is why the whole issue is somewhat baffling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and change `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal` - then it will update.

Comment: This did the trick. Was finally able to upgrade after I implemented this change. Thank you!

Comment: Good that this works for you.

However, there are IMHO 2 contra-intuïtive things in this:
-Drahkar says he had 15.10 which is not an LTS, how did the `"Prompt=lts" ` end up in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`?
-16.04 is an LTS, why does it require `Prompt=normal`?

This sounds like buggy behaviour to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
$ sudo update-manager -d
```

Then a window should pop up, checking for new releases and you should be able to select "Actualize to 16.04." (or similar)

At least this is how I did it.

Comment: "upgrade" ... not "updrage" I would edit but for edit to save there must be at least 6 characters modified.

Comment: That ultimately ends up with the same issue as running `sudo do-release-upgrade -cd` where it acts like there is nothing to update. The whole thing is reacting like it does not see any available updates, regardless to what setting I change it to. Development releases, proposed releases, all end up saying there are no updates. Figured the next step was to see if anyone else had suggestions, so here I am.

Comment: @NonStandardModel just delete the whole word "updrage" and type "upgrade"... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It took a few days after the release day, but upgrading to 16.04 is now enabled, so 15.10 users should normally be notified when running *Software Updater* (and `do-release-upgrade` should find 16.04).