# Why does do-release-upgrade try to upgrade my system to 15.10, and how to I make it upgrade to 16.04?

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, 16.04, versions, do-release-upgrade

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and I decided it was a good time to update to the latest version. However, if I run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The program starts downloading Wily Werewolf (15.10) packages. How can I force Ubuntu to download Xenial Xerus?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next)

Comment: Run `do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: `~ $ sudo do-release-upgrade -d

Checking for a new Ubuntu release

Err Upgrade tool signature
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err Upgrade tool
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)
WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.`

Comment: For the record, I am able to `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` correctly, and `do-release-upgrade` without the `-d` correctly.

Comment: Does your `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file end in `Prompt=lts`? If not, change it and try again.  I just did this successfully in a VM.

Comment: @MartínFixman Great! How about I post it as an answer then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing the `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, make sure that your `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file ends in `Prompt=lts`.  This will enable the upgrade tool to fetch the next LTS release (16.04) instead of just the next release (15.10).

Comment: Should he backup his data ?

Comment: He should also wear a seatbelt in a motor vehicle.  But these are not things he asked about.

Comment: Yeah I maybe he has nine lives and should pay for reincarnation services ... Where's be nice now?, when you gotta think.

Comment: Seriously, if you look at the comments on the original question, he already tried it and it worked for him.

Comment: Ok I'll delete my answer then.

Comment: I'll just leave this here - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324051&p=13486842#post13486842

Answer (score -1):

You will be able to have your 14.04 LTS version identified ad upgradable to the 16.04 LTS version when the first 'Point Release' for 16.04.1 is available - currently scheduled for July 21, 2016. [Announced release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule)

If your desire is to test your current hardware and software compatibility with Xenial you can make a live session of Xenial for testing.
[Make a persistent USB instance.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)

Comment: So concise, pertinent, correct information is downgraded!