# Why a prompt to Update 14.04 to 15.10?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, updates

I am trying to eventually update to 16.04 from 14.04. I'd prefer not to do a fresh install nor backup my installation (my data is backed up at SpiderOak...)

Do I have to... or is it easiest to update first to 14.10 and then 15.04 and so on? If this is the case, if the problems or "damage" will occur otherwise, why, after running update-manager, do I only get a prompt to  update straight to 15.10?

Can I just update LTS version to LTS version without going through the x.10 releases? How do I do this, or do what's best? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading directly should work fine (14.10 and 15.04 are EOL anyway). However, [LTS to LTS upgrades won't show up until the first point release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next) ("first point release" in this case meaning 16.04.1). You can override this and upgrade anyway by running `do-release-upgrade -d` in the terminal, but it's typically better to wait for the first point release, which is scheduled for July 21st.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly upgrade from a LTS version (14.04 in your case) to the first point release of the next LTS version (16.04.1) by running:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Note that, however, the first point release of 16.04 is not out yet. If you still want to upgrade to 16.04 before then, you add the `-d` option to the previous command:

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```