# 18.04 not available in Software Updater

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I want to upgrade to Bionic Beaver from 17.10, but the Software Updater says everything is up to date.

I followed [this](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop?_ga=2.190419307.195510643.1524777452-327690542.1524777452#0) but at the step the upgrade button should pop in Software Updater it still says everything is up to date. I did change the settings to notify me for "Any new version".

What else could be wrong?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next This questions solves it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

Comment: Actually Ubuntu 18.04 *is not yet available for upgrade*. It says so right on their download page. You can only get it via clean install for now. Upgrade will be available later next month.

Comment: luckily for me it is next next and almost next month :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to upgrade Ubuntu to the next release is via `sudo do-release-upgrade`. But to be safe and avoid possible errors after the upgrade, make sure that your current release is up to date first:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

You'll probably want to `sudo apt autoremove` useless packages too.

Finally make sure you have *update-manager-core*  and start the upgrade:

```
sudo apt install update-manager-core && sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: `sudo do-release-upgrade` gave me `No new release found.`