# Follow up to Upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 17.10

I am following the instructions here to upgrade Ubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04. But when I run `update-manager -d` I get errors:

> No protocol specified Unable to init server: Could not connect:
>   Connection refused No protocol specified Unable to init server: Could
>   not connect: Connection refused No protocol specified Unable to init
>   server: Could not connect: Connection refused
>
> (update-manager:7789): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

[18.04 not available in Software Updater](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028575/18-04-not-available-in-software-updater)

Comment: Are you running this from a terminal on your GUI?  or are you logged into a Wayland session (as I recall it was the default in 17.10) as that command requires X11 to be used.  You don't need the `-d` option as 18.04 has been released (-d or development-release is now 19.04 where you're a few steps behind).  If using a terminal, upgrade first to latest 17.10 (`sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`) then `do-release-upgrade` is a non-gui alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't gksu/gksudo or launching a graphical application with sudo work with Wayland?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961967/why-dont-gksu-gksudo-or-launching-a-graphical-application-with-sudo-work-with-w) && https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/480481