# Software Updater on 16.04 not showing Ubuntu 18.04 update

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

Software Updater on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't show Ubuntu 18.04 update. I have checked and all settings are good.

What do I need to do?

Comment: This appears to be a general problem. Although the 18.04 iso is available it is still not possible to upgrade using 'sudo apt dist-upgrade' and "sudo do-release-upgrade' results in the message "No new release found." Perhaps 18.04 will be available for upgrade soon.

Answer (score 11):

From this [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_or_17.10) we have the notice:

> #### Upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or 17.10
>
> Upgrades from 17.10 will not be enabled until a few days after 18.04's release. Upgrades from 16.04 LTS will not be enabled until a few days after the 18.04.1 release expected in [late July](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule).

Comment: It's already few days are gone, but there is still no update found unfortunately. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS has been released the 26 July and the command `do-release-upgrade` still says "No new release found". Any idea why? There was the same problem for 14.04.1 LTS (https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next) and it is still not listed here: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts

Comment: @baptx I have no idea.