# Upgrading ubuntu 16.04lts to 18.04lts

Tags: upgrade

I have been trying to update my ubuntu 16.04lts to 18.04lts and am getting these errors:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

This can be caused by: 
* Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu 
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
```

When I check the error log in /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log
This is what I get

```
Broken libqt5core5a:amd64 Breaks on libqt5scintilla2-12v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.9.1+dfsg-4build1 > ( libs ) (< 2.9.2+dfsg-2~)
Broken libdouble-conversion1:amd64 Breaks on libdouble-conversion1v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.0.1-3ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libcurl4:amd64 Conflicts on libcurl3 [ amd64 ] < 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.8 -> 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 > ( universe/libs )
Broken libpeas-1.0-0:amd64 Conflicts on libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader [ amd64 ] < 1.16.0-1ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken gnome-control-center-faces:amd64 Conflicts on unity-control-center-faces [ amd64 ] < 15.04.0+16.04.20171130-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken libsane1:amd64 Conflicts on libsane [ amd64 ] < 1.0.25+git20150528-1ubuntu2.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (< 1.0.27-1~)
Broken libdbusmenu-qt5-2:amd64 Breaks on libdbusmenu-qt5 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken apparmor:amd64 Breaks on webbrowser-app [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
Broken kactivitymanagerd:amd64 Breaks on kactivities [ amd64 ] < 5.18.0-0ubuntu1 > ( libs ) (< 5.20~)
Broken aptdaemon:amd64 Breaks on python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat [ amd64 ] < 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 > ( python )
Broken libgjs0g:amd64 Conflicts on libgjs0e [ amd64 ] < 1.44.0-1ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken imagemagick-6-common:amd64 Breaks on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11 > ( libs ) (< 8:6.9.6.2+dfsg-3~)
Broken gnome-software:amd64 Depends on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2 > ( admin ) (>= 1.1.4)
Broken libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:amd64 Breaks on libwebkitgtk-1.0-common [ amd64 ] < 2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (< 2.4.11-2~)
Broken libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni:amd64 Depends on libswt-gtk-3-jni [ amd64 ] < 3.8.2-3 -> 3.8.2-5 > ( universe/libs ) (= 3.8.2-3)
Broken gnome-software-plugin-snap:amd64 Depends on gnome-software [ amd64 ] < 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11 -> 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1 > ( gnome ) (= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1)
Broken vlc-bin:amd64 Breaks on vlc-nox [ amd64 ] < 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 > ( video ) (< 3.0.0-1~)
Broken qml-module-ubuntu-components:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken grilo-plugins-0.3-base:amd64 Breaks on grilo-plugins-0.2-base [ amd64 ] < 0.2.17-0ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken libreadline-dev:amd64 Conflicts on libreadline6-dev [ amd64 ] < 6.3-8ubuntu2 > ( libdevel )
Broken unity-session:amd64 Breaks on upstart [ amd64 ] < 1.13.2-0ubuntu21.1 > ( admin ) (< 1.13.2-0ubuntu28~)
Broken qml-module-ubuntu-layouts:amd64 Depends on qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken qml-module-ubuntu-test:amd64 Depends on qml-module-ubuntu-components [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken liboxideqtcore0:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken libabw-0.1-1:amd64 Conflicts on libabw-0.1-1v5 [ amd64 ] < 0.1.1-2ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 Conflicts on gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly-amr [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1 > ( libs ) (< 1.11.91)
Broken ubuntu-software:amd64 Depends on gnome-software [ amd64 ] < 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11 -> 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1 > ( gnome ) (>= 3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.1)
Broken fwupd:amd64 Breaks on libdfu1 [ amd64 ] < 0.8.3-0ubuntu3 > ( admin ) (< 0.9.7-1)
Broken gnome-themes-extra-data:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-themes-standard-data [ amd64 ] < 3.18.0-2ubuntu2 -> 3.22.3-3ubuntu2 > ( universe/gnome )
Broken gnome-themes-extra-data:amd64 Conflicts on gnome-themes-standard-data [ i386 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken liboxideqtquick0:amd64 Depends on liboxideqtcore0 [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (= 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
Broken gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0:amd64 Conflicts on gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 [ amd64 ] < 3.10.6-1ubuntu1 > ( introspection )
Broken libqscintilla2-qt5-l10n:amd64 Breaks on libqt5scintilla2-l10n [ amd64 ] < 2.9.1+dfsg-4build1 > ( libs ) (< 2.10)
Broken libsidplay2:amd64 Conflicts on libsidplay2v5 [ amd64 ] < 2.1.1-14ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken kerneloops:amd64 Breaks on kerneloops-daemon [ amd64 ] < 0.12+git20140509-2ubuntu1 > ( utils ) (< 0.12+git20140509-6ubuntu1)
Broken gstreamer1.0-packagekit:amd64 Depends on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2 > ( admin ) (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu2)
Broken libubuntugestures5:amd64 Depends on qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on gstreamer1.0-packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2 > ( libs )
Broken webapp-container:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken libdbd-pg-perl:amd64 Depends on perlapi-5.22.1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken libubuntutoolkit5:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken perl-modules-5.22:amd64 Conflicts on perl-modules [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken libmutter0g:amd64 Depends on mutter-common [ amd64 ] < 3.18.3-0ubuntu2 -> 3.28.1-1ubuntu1 > ( misc ) (= 3.18.3-0ubuntu2)
Broken libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 Depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
Broken libvlccore8:amd64 Depends on vlc-data [ amd64 ] < 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4 -> 3.0.2-0ubuntu0.1 > ( universe/graphics ) (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4)
Broken packagekit-tools:amd64 Depends on packagekit [ amd64 ] < none -> 1.1.9-1ubuntu2 > ( admin ) (= 1.1.9-1ubuntu2)
Broken libnss3-nssdb:amd64 Depends on libnss3 [ amd64 ] < 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 -> 2:3.35-2ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (= 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3)
Broken calligraplan:amd64 Depends on calligra-libs [ amd64 ] < 1:2.9.7-0ubuntu12 -> 1:3.0.1-0ubuntu4 > ( universe/libs ) (= 1:2.9.7-0ubuntu12)
Broken idle-python3.5:amd64 Depends on python3.5-tk [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken gir1.2-mutter-3.0:amd64 Depends on libmutter0g [ amd64 ] < 3.18.3-0ubuntu2 > ( libs ) (= 3.18.3-0ubuntu2)
Broken appmenu-qt5:amd64 Depends on libdbusmenu-qt5 [ amd64 ] < 0.9.3+16.04.20160218-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad:amd64 Depends on libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 -> 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2)
Broken libmetacity-private3a:amd64 Depends on metacity-common [ amd64 ] < 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3 -> 1:3.28.0-1 > ( universe/misc ) (= 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.3)
Broken pulseaudio-module-x11:amd64 Depends on libpulse0 [ amd64 ] < 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10 -> 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1 > ( libs ) (= 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10)
Broken libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 Depends on libmagickcore-6.q16-2 [ amd64 ] < 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11 > ( libs ) (>= 8:6.8.9.9)
Broken gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers:amd64 Depends on libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 [ amd64 ] < 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2 -> 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 > ( universe/libs ) (= 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2)
Broken ora2pg:amd64 Depends on libdbd-pg-perl [ amd64 ] < 3.7.4-1~pgdg16.04+1 > ( perl )
Broken qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin:amd64 Depends on qml-module-ubuntu-components [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( libs )
Broken liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64 Depends on liboxideqtcore0 [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (= 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Depends on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
Broken qml-module-ubuntu-web:amd64 Depends on liboxideqt-qmlplugin [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.15)
Broken libperl5.22:amd64 Depends on perl-modules-5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 > ( perl ) (>= 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5)
Broken webapp-container:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken unity-webapps-qml:amd64 Depends on liboxideqt-qmlplugin [ amd64 ] < 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 > ( libs ) (>= 1.3.0)
Broken unity-webapps-qml:amd64 Depends on qml-module-qtwebkit [ amd64 ] < none -> 5.212.0~alpha2-7ubuntu1 > ( universe/libs )
Broken unity-webapps-qml:amd64 Depends on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
Broken unity-webapps-qml:amd64 Depends on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken checkbox-converged:amd64 Depends on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
Broken postgresql-plperl-9.6:amd64 Depends on libperl5.22 [ amd64 ] < 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.5 > ( libs ) (>= 5.22.1)
Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Depends on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Depends on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
Broken webapp-container:amd64 Depends on qtbase-abi-5-5-1 [ amd64 ] < none ->  > ( none )
Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Depends on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
Broken unity-webapps-service:amd64 Depends on webapp-container [ amd64 ] < 0.23+16.04.20161028-0ubuntu2 > ( x11 )
Broken libunity-webapps0:amd64 Depends on unity-webapps-service [ amd64 ] < 2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome )
Broken checkbox-converged:amd64 Depends on qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin [ amd64 ] < 1.3.1918+16.04.20160404-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
Broken checkbox-gui:amd64 Depends on checkbox-converged [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
Broken unity-webapps-common:amd64 Depends on unity-webapps-service [ amd64 ] < 2.5.0~+16.04.20160201-0ubuntu1 > ( gnome ) (>= 2.3.8-0ubuntu3)
Broken ubuntu-desktop:amd64 Depends on checkbox-gui [ amd64 ] < 1.2.4-0ubuntu1 > ( oldlibs )
```

Please Help

Comment: Did you run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` as [recommended for a pre-release upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next)?

Comment: @Takkat Yes and am getting the same error.