# Help! Trying to upgrade 18.04 to 20.04.1, but upgrade button does nothing

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04

I could use some help in figuring out why the Upgrade button on the software updater doesn't do anything. I did some googling and answers were that I had updates that weren't installed. So, I `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. It says that there was 1 not upgraded. I'm pretty sure that `sudo apt-get --upgradeable -a` would list the package that needs to be updated and it showed:

`nick@nick-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs0xxx:~$ apt list --upgradable -a Listing... Done calendar-indicator/bionic,bionic 0.4.0-0extras19.04.1 all [upgradable from: 0.3.4-0extras15.10.0] calendar-indicator/now 0.3.4-0extras15.10.0 all [installed,upgradable to: 0.4.0-0extras19.04.1]`

So am I on the right path here? Is the calendar-indicator the stuck package? How would I go about getting it to update so I can upgrade to 20.04 via the software updater?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604 (upgrades not enabled yet ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to update `calendar-indicator` to a version that's newer than your current 18.04.

I'd check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` files for the atareao PPA, and verify that it's got the proper current system name in the deb line.

For the short term... you can uninstall `calendar-indicator`, do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, to install any possible outstanding installs, then the UPGRADE button in `Software Updater` should work. Then after the 20.04.1 upgrade is complete, reinstall `calendar-indicator` if you wish to.

See: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/atareao_atareao/focal/main/base/calendar-indicator

See: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/atareao_atareao?dist=focal

Comment: I found the ppa in the /etc/apt/sources,list.d/*.list and this is what it shows:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu bionic main

How do I know if it's proper? Based on the links you included, the URL is different, but I'm not sure if that makes a difference. I apologize. Though I've used Ubuntu daily for the last year, I'm still not very good at troubleshooting stuff this in-depth.

Comment: @NickD Your PPA definition looks fine. Go ahead and do paragraph #3 in my answer. Report back. And don't worry... we were all newbies once, and it does take some time to know where to start troubleshooting stuff :-)

Comment: Thank you! I've removed calendar-inidcator and am now able to upgrade to 20.04! Definitely looking forward to the upgrade since 18.04 has felt rather stale and outdated since I started using it.

Comment: @NickD Great news! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 5):

If your are trying to upgrade from 18.04 (LTS version) to 20.04 (LTS version) you'll have to wait for the first point release. This would be 20.04.1. As it currently stands, this release is out. So why does the updater not update? Because the metadata file is not yet updated. Wait for the folks at Ubuntu to update [the metadata](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts), so it lists Focal Fossa.
(Based on [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next#comment680752_125492))