# Why does do-release-upgrade on Xubuntu running version 18.04 not offer to update to 20.04.1?

Tags: updates, xubuntu, do-release-upgrade

I've understood that when I run the Software Updater GUI program, or when I execute `do-release-upgrade` on the command line, it should offer to upgrade to the latest LTS release if (1) I've got the release update behaviour set to `lts`, and (2) if the first point release of a newer LTS release is available.

I have a couple of machines running the Xubuntu LTS release 18.04. The contents of file `etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` on all these machines is

```
[DEFAULT]
Prompt=lts
```

That satisfies condition (1). Also, it seems that Xubuntu 20.04.1 is already released, satisfying condition (2). However, neither `do-release-upgrade` nor the Software Updater offers to upgrade to that release. Why?

**Edited to add:** It seems this question is a duplicate of ["Why isn't an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 available yet?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266902/why-isnt-an-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-available-yet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The Ubuntu Release Team has delayed point releases in the past to ensure a safe transition for the largest number of folks.
2. In this case, 20.04.1's release took place on a Thursday. The Release Team has historically been (understandably) reluctant to enable upgrades for millions of machines right before they leave for the weekend.
3. Some systems cannot be upgraded quite yet due to [blocking bugs](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604)

Comment: I understand the reasoning of your point 2, but not points 1 and 3. Isn't the expected delay the one between the XX.YY and XX.YY.1 releases, and should the XX.YY.1 release not be the one that fixes any bugs that block upgrades from a previous release? Once XX.YY.1 is released, isn't it frozen? That is, if there are any blocking bugs in XX.YY.1, then should users not delay upgrading until a new point release, XX.YY.2, that fixes those bugs?

Comment: @TeemuLeisti Ubuntu uses scheduled releases that generally occur six months apart. A critical bug blocking a release will not wait six months for the next scheduled release.

Comment: OK, so does that mean that sometimes release XX.YY.1.0 is not considered an LTS release that `do-release-upgrade` will offer to upgrade to (without the use of the `-d` switch), but instead some later release XX.YY.1.n, where n > 0, might be?

Comment: @TeemuLeisti only LTS releases have subsequent point releases. Migration from 18.04.x to 20.04 (April release) requires the -d flag because normal upgrade path for LTS is **not opened** until 20.04.1. It is standard for LTS-to-LTS migration to wait until XX.YY.1. Since it only occurs every two years, folks forget.

Comment: OK, but I wasn't asking about the difference between XX.YY.1 and XX.YY.2, but rather XX.YY.1.0 (or whatever the version naming convention for the fourth level is) and XX.YY.1.n. My tentative reasoning is that since it seems that the first point release's first version, XX.YY.1.0, might not be of sufficient quality to be visible to `do-release-upgrade` (without using the `-d` flag), then it must be that the first visible version is XX.YY.1.n, where n > 0?

Comment: To clarify: it seems I already have **a** version of Xubuntu 20.04.1, installed by commanding `do-release-upgrade -d`, as command `hostnamectl` on my machine outputs `Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`. There must therefore be at least **one** version of 20.04.1 available for download. Since we're expecting a later, better version to be offered as an upgrade target when one commands `do-release-upgrade` (without switches), that must be a bugfix version? (I tried googling for information about how the Ubuntu releases work, and how they use bugfix versioning, but didn't find anything.)

Comment: @TeemuLeisti When the Blocking Bugs are resolved, the fixes will go out to all Ubuntu systems that already have 20.04.1 installed via normal apt update. Your current 20.04.1 *will be* identical to a newly do-release-upgraded 20.04.1. The link to those Blocking Bugs is in paragraph 3 of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your patience with my questions. I'll mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: 3. Was the first answer to this question to point at literally what blocks upgrade enablement.  Thank you.

Comment: There is a lot of truth to this answer.  I forced an upgrade a couple of days ago after the point release and it did not go well.  It upgraded, but then applications started uninstalling when I was running apt upgrade and it killed my system.  I ended up clean installing my system, but I am even seeing bugs as is.  So, it is best still to wait which is what I am going to do with my other 18.04 LTS system.

Answer (score 5):

you are right with your two conditions (upgrade behaviour set to LTS and first point release is released) and you are right that both conditions are met by now.

However, there is a third condition that needs to be fulfilled. That is "Upgrades from 18.04 to 20.04.1 are enabled". This is an extra step that needs to be activated by the team.

This has not been done so far. Actual status is "20.04.1 Released! - Upgrades from 18.04 to 20.04.1 still disabled" You can see the status [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604). The reason is that they are still working on some "upgrade blockers". I would expect upgrades to be activated in the next few days.

Hope that helps!

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Indeed: if your are trying to upgrade from 18.04 (LTS version) to 20.04 (LTS version) you'll have to wait for the first point release. This would be 20.04.1. As it currently stands, this release is out. So why does the updater not update? Because the metadata file is not yet updated. Wait for the folks at Ubuntu to update [the metadata](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts), so it lists Focal Fossa.
(Based on [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next#comment680752_125492))

Comment: That might well be it. The comment you linked to was made in 2012, so this problem seems to be at least eight years old.

Comment: I suspect it's not actually a problem, but more a conservative choice of the people at Ubuntu. I think that, when there are no signs of destroyed Ubuntu installations on Twitter, blogs or newssites, they will update the metadata, and have everyone update. Or, it might be to spare the mirrors a bit: some people will manually upgrade to the next LTS, some people will wait for the metadata update.

Comment: Maybe so. I've manually upgraded two of my three machines by commanding `do-release-upgrade -d`. I guess I'll do that for the third one, too.

Answer (score 0):

Open Software & Updates -> Updates ->
Notify me of a new Ubuntu Version -> For any new version. (change)
Close.
Then sudo apt update.

Comment: This is not an answer to my question.