# Why isn't an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 available yet?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I want to use `do-release-upgrade` to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04, but I can't do that

```
do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
```

It seems that [this file](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) is used, and it still points to 18.04.

Do you know when (or how?) can I upgrade to 20.04?

Comment: Please update the status when the bug is fixed. Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to wait, an official blog tells you how - https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today

Comment: Stable upgrade is now available! :D

Answer (score 85, accepted):

See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604 for the current status.

On 25 September 2020, the final upgrade-blocking bug was closed.

If you are reading this on 25-27 September, just be patient while your local mirror catches up.

Comment: Your answer is super useful. I just wanted to suggest to keep all the historic (i.e. the previous dates you mentionned).

Comment: It suggests that [this launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1891680) is blocking upgrades, but yet the launchpad janitor claims that a fix has been released?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs I understood what the OP mean; I noticed that he removed the point as of August 27th (when 2 bugs were blocking) and I think that this historic information is valuable.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs read the Launchpad Janitor message closely. It has been resolved for Groovy only...and no others yet. Historical data is conveniently available in the edit history of the discourse thread.

Comment: According to comment on the upgrade bug, upgrade is already available without `-d`.

Comment: I received message: "Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS is now avaiable" via Software Updater today. But looking at your link, it still showed status "Upgrades from 18.04 to 20.04.1 still disabled". What does this mean?

Comment: @lehien I'm not sure what you are looking it. When I click my link, it says *Current Blockers: None* and *Status: Released*.

Comment: @user535733 I clicked your link and it says:
Status
    20.04.1 Released!
    Upgrades from 18.04 to 20.04.1 still disabled
Current Blockers: None
So it is different between region?

Comment: Today, the page says *Upgrades from 18.04 to 20.04.1 enabled!*

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Will get you safely upgraded today, but please verify *before upgrading* that you are not affected by the blocking bugs mentioned above by user535733.

Comment: This is actually better than manually editing sources.list.

Comment: This works because 20.04 is still flagged as a developmental release until they sort out those blocking bugs.

Since 19.10 is no longer the most recent developmental release, upgrading this way with the "-d" flag is the simplest way to upgrade "now" before 20.04 is formally flagged as LTS, and it won't compromise your preference to stick to future LTS releases going forward.

Comment: The remaining blocking bug, in layman's terms is a problem in certain cloud environments, where a disk boot record is not used. If your system uses a physical disk, the bug should not be able to affect you and you can safely upgrade.

Comment: `-d` does not work for me (18.04.1), and apparently I'm not the only one. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254519/problem-upragding-to-focal-fossa-20-04-authenticate-focal-tar-gz-against-foca

Answer (score 5):

If you have a 32-bit installation then you will never be offered an upgrade to 20.04 because it is not supported anymore.
If this is the case then your only way is to reinstall with the 64-bit version ;-(

How to check quickly: In a terminal enter

```
uname -m
```

If this gives you i686 and not x86_64 then you have 32-bit installation.

Hope that helps