# Ubuntu 20.04.1 has been released one week ago but is not proposed as an upgrade by my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

My system is currently running Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu 20.04.1 has been out one week ago, yet it is not proposed as an upgrade by the software manager:

[image]

A call to `sudo do-release-upgrade -c` returns

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

Am I being impatient, or is something wrong here?

(In case that is relevant, I was actually running 16.04, and wanted to switch to 20.04 once the first point release is out. Hopping to 18.04 is a necessary step in the process -- this one happened flawlessly).

Comment: It could be, though we are one week after the release, not a few hours as in the post you link to. Are 18.04 users still denied the 20.04.1 update when asking for LTS updates only at this time?

Comment: The wording *hours* was used because I wrote that answer in what I considered *hours*, ie. what would now be last week.  If you check up the current status, there are two *show stopped* bugs that in in play, one was marked *fix released* last I looked, but loads of other minor issues too.  LTS users want stability, so rushing it is not advised. Canonical provided *how to force upgrade* instructions if you don't want to wait.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.7 and Ubuntu 18.04.5 were also released today... the release team were also somewhat focused on those scheduled releases (okay, 16.04.7 wasn't as *scheduled* as most, but it still used resources..), so pushing upgrades during the current period may also have reduced quality... and I'd prize the delay & quality/stability myself... My 2c  (by *today* I mean it's less than 24 hours since release, it may be yesterday depending on where you are in the world..)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the insight. Being impatient was the correct answer then :)

Comment: There are several similiar threads over the past few days [Why isn't an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 available yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266902/why-isnt-an-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-available-yet)