# Can't upgrade server 18.04.05 to 20.04.01

Tags: do-release-upgrade

```
17:37UTC:root@bard:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

17:38UTC:root@bard:~# do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.`
```

Why does my upgrade manager say there is no "development" version of an LTS available?

```
17:41UTC:root@bard:~# cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#    
#  never  - Never check for, or allow upgrading to, a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the supported release that immediately succeeds the
#           currently-running release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that if this option is used and
#           the currently-running release is not itself an LTS release the
#           upgrader will assume prompt was meant to be normal.
Prompt=lts
```

This system has [what looks to me like] a generic `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Points to various `ubuntu.com` Bionic repositories.

??

Comment: There are several similiar threads over the past few days [Why isn't an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 available yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266902/why-isnt-an-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-available-yet)

Answer (score 2):

oh! special situation: critical bug(s) for which Canonical is holding back Focal. The "point" release (20.04.01) is out, but it's not "released" yet for upgrades from 18.04LTS

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604