# Problem updating 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, 20.04, dependencies

I tried to update from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 on my computer but I got an error of too many unmet dependencies.

I tried several things (unsucessfully) such as:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I will appreciate your help, as I am stuck and cannot update my system. The configuration looks something in between 18.04 and 20.04 as I have installed 20.04 on another PC and some options such as dark scheme are not available (config still looks as 18.04)

`lsb_release` says I am in 20.4:

```
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  
Release:    20.04  
Codename:   focal
```

I have a SSD with the OS. Tried also to use a boot USB with 20.04 to reinstall completely linux but does not load the OS and the computer hangs up. I verified that the USB is working OK as I can load Ubuntu 20.04 on another computer.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Here you have I error log:

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Corrigiendo dependencias... falló.
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 : Depende: gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 (>= 2.40.0) pero 2.36.11-2 está instalado
                  Depende: gir1.2-pango-1.0 (>= 1.41.0) pero 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 está instalado
                  Depende: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.24.7) pero 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 está instalado
 gnupg : Depende: gpgv (>= 2.2.19-3ubuntu2)
 gnupg-utils : Depende: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) pero no está instalado
 gpg : Depende: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) pero no está instalado
 gpgconf : Depende: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) pero no está instalado
 gpgsm : Depende: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) pero no está instalado
 grub-common : Depende: libefiboot1 (>= 37) pero 34-1 está instalado
               Depende: libefivar1 (>= 37) pero 34-1 está instalado
 grub2-common : Depende: libefiboot1 (>= 37) pero 34-1 está instalado
                Depende: libefivar1 (>= 37) pero 34-1 está instalado
 hplip : Depende: hplip-data (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) pero 3.17.10+repack0-5 está instalado
         Depende: libhpmud0 (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) pero 3.17.10+repack0-5 está instalado
         Depende: printer-driver-hpcups (= 3.20.3+dfsg0-2) pero 3.17.10+repack0-5 está instalado
         Depende: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) pero no está instalado
 initramfs-tools-core : Depende: initramfs-tools-bin (= 0.136ubuntu6) pero 0.130ubuntu3.9 está instalado
                        Depende: lz4
 klibc-utils : Depende: libklibc (= 2.0.7-1ubuntu5) pero 2.0.4-9ubuntu2 está instalado
 libglib-object-introspection-perl : Depende: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) pero 1.56.1-1 está instalado
 libglib2.0-bin : Depende: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1) pero 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 está instalado
 libglib2.0-dev : Depende: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.64.2-1~fakesync1) pero 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 está instalado
 libgtk-3-dev : Depende: libfribidi-dev (>= 0.19.7) pero no está instalado
                Depende: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.40.0) pero 2.36.11-2 está instalado
                Depende: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.41) pero 1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1 está instalado
                Depende: wayland-protocols (>= 1.14) pero 1.13-1 está instalado
                Depende: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.24.18-1ubuntu1) pero 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 está instalado
 libpython3.8-stdlib : Depende: libreadline8 (>= 7.0~beta) pero no está instalado
 libsane-hpaio : Depende: libhpmud0 (>= 3.20.3+dfsg0) pero 3.17.10+repack0-5 está instalado
 libx11-dev : Depende: libx11-6 (= 2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1) pero 2:1.6.4-3ubuntu0.2 está instalado
 mailutils : Depende: guile-2.2-libs pero no está instalado
             Depende: libmailutils6 pero no está instalado
             Depende: libncurses6 (>= 6) pero no está instalado
             Depende: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) pero no está instalado
             Depende: libreadline8 (>= 6.0) pero no está instalado
 python3-brlapi : Depende: libbrlapi0.7 pero no está instalado
 python3-dev : Depende: libpython3-dev (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2) pero 3.6.7-1~18.04 está instalado
               Depende: python3.8-dev (>= 3.8.2-1~) pero no está instalado
 python3-gi : Depende: libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 1.62.0-4~) pero 1.56.1-1 está instalado
 python3-pil : Depende: libimagequant0 (>= 2.11.10) pero no está instalado
 python3-protobuf : Depende: libprotobuf17 pero no está instalado
 python3-pyqt5 : Depende: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) pero no está instalado
                 Depende: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.4) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
                 Depende: libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.12.2) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
                 Depende: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.12.2) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado o
                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.12.2) pero no está instalado
                 Depende: libqt5network5 (>= 5.12.2) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
                 Depende: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.10.0) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
                 Depende: libqt5test5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
                 Depende: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.12.2) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
                 Depende: qtbase-abi-5-12-8
 python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia : Depende: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
                              Depende: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.11.1) pero 5.9.5-0ubuntu1 está instalado
 python3-pyqt5.qtopengl : Depende: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
 python3-pyqt5.qtsvg : Depende: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
 python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit : Depende: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) pero 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu2.5 está instalado
                          Depende: libqt5webkit5 (>= 5.212.0~alpha3) pero 5.212.0~alpha2-7ubuntu1 está instalado
 python3-uno : Depende: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) pero 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10 está instalado o
                        libreoffice-core-nogui (= 1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) pero no está instalado
               Depende: libpython3.8 (>= 3.8.2) pero no está instalado
               Depende: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) pero no está instalado
               Depende: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) pero no está instalado
               Depende: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.4.0~alpha) pero no está instalado
               Depende: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) pero no está instalado
               Depende: uno-libs-private pero no está instalado
 rhythmbox-plugins : Depende: librhythmbox-core10 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) pero 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 está instalado
                     Depende: rhythmbox (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) pero 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 está instalado
                     Depende: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 3.4.4-1ubuntu2) pero 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 está instalado
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generó cortes, esto puede deberse a paquetes retenidos.
E: No se pueden corregir las dependencias
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 available yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266902/why-isnt-an-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-available-yet)

Comment: *I tried to update from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04:* How? Which command did you use? Did you edit sources.list?