# Doesnt appear upgrade prompt on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, ubuntu-studio

Hello i have ubuntu desktop 18.04.5 with latest updates.. But dont know why the prompt i should read doesnt appear :

[image]

I only have the line The software on this computer is up-to date.And thats it...

I also would like to pass from "normal" Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 to Ubuntu Studio 20.04.1 if possible ( as i have bought a usb audio interface and want to make some tests with djinng and music).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend reading the Ubuntu Studio 20.04 release notes. Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release, so to continue *extended* support they requested you add a PPA. To upgrade however, they recommend `ppa-purge` of that PPA additions before you *release-upgrade* to 20.04 http://ubuntustudio.org/2020/04/ubuntu-studio-20-04-lts-released/\

Comment: Also be aware the upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 has been enabled for main repository, if you're using a mirror, it may not yet appear (some are hours to day(s) behind) so I'd not panic yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 available yet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266902/why-isnt-an-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-available-yet)

Comment: @N0rbert Te problem in this question has been solved, and the answer was not found in the answers to your linked duplicate question. The reason for this is that it has already been enough time since the release of the first Ubuntu 20.04 point release that a different solution to being unable to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 is required to enable the upgrade to proceed successfully. I recommend leaving a separate question (this one) for this topic open for answering similar questions about upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 from now forward.

Comment: @N0rbert I'm very happy that I got the accept vote on this question. This is as I see it a critically important question to the Ubuntu community because it provides the possibility of an upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 when all other options fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 in the terminal with `do-release-upgrade -d` and copy the error message into a text file. The error message will probably say which log file to look in to display the complete error message. An uncorrected error can block your upgrade forever, but if you correct the error the upgrade will proceed normally. **Note:** Please simulate all corrections before running them to avoid crippling your operating system.

When I tried this on my Ubuntu 18.04 the results were that three Python 2.x packages could not be upgraded, and that was blocking the upgrade from
Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. I simulated uninstalling each of these packages one by one. Uninstalling two of the three packages would also have uninstalled about 1GB of other packages that had these packages as a dependency. Uninstalling the third package with `apt remove --simulate <package>` simulated only uninstalling itself and removed no other packages. After uninstalling this package the upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 proceeded to the end without errors.

> Thanks. I think all went the right way. I found the problem that this repository is not available: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease, so I changed it to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease.

Comment: And its possible to upgrade to ubuntu Studio 20.04 ? I think now is safer to upgrade as many people would have been upgrading before me ;)

Comment: I think it would be safer to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 instead of upgrading sideways to Ubuntu Studio 20.04. After upgrading you can install whatever Ubuntu Studio packages that you need in Ubuntu 20.04. This method would let you install all the packages that you need and give you a safer upgrade.

Comment: Thanks i think all went the right way... i found this problem: that this repository is not avalaible.... http://achive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease, so i changed  to http://achive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease....So i think its right....

Comment: @EduardoGutierrez If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Comment: after updating to 20.04 im some housecleaning.... and i met this: https://pastebin.com/5qULJ3eP  ( relevant begins in line 6 with deborphan) I think i should remove package python-is-python2 which has lots of dependencies ( its marked as deprecated) and then install pytho-is-python3. I read you have some problems with python2 packages, perhaps you can help me or give some advice... thanks

Comment: @EduardoGutierrez For a test I ran `apt install --simulate python-is-python2` in 20.04 and the simulation didn't break anything, but I think you should remove python-is-python2 with `sudo apt remove python-is-python2` because you don't need it. Python 2.x is end of life since January, 2020 anyway. You don't need `python-is-python3` either, but it can protect you from making mistakes in the terminal.

Comment: In my case, the message was: "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.". So 18.04 needed more updates before the release upgrade to 20.04 can proceed

Comment: @prusswan I already upgraded the software in 18.04, so I didn't get that message before upgrading. Instead my problem was that I had obsolete software in 18.04 that needed to be uninstalled in order for the release upgrade to continue.