# updating from 20.04.4 to 22.04

Tags: do-release-upgrade

Hi I am trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04.4. I used the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

I end up getting this error

```
Upgrades to the development release are only available from the latest supported release.
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Are you sure that you are on 20.04 ? What is the output of `lsn-release -a` ? Also make sure that `.d` is still needed, it is some time ago that 22.04 was released, so maybe the update don't need "development" option any more,

Comment: @user535733 in the time between the release of ex. 22.04 in april and the first point-release (22.02.01) the update will still have to be performed with `-d`. Around the time of the point-release Canonical will set up the next development-branch (for 22.10 this time) and the meaning of `-d` will "change" from 22.04 to 22.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next) While the question is slightly different, the same answer applies.