# Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 13

Tags: dell

I have Ubuntu 20.04 pre-installed on my Dell XPS 13 laptop.   I would like to know if an upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 is possible now.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Advisable is an entirely different can of worms.

Comment: Boot live installer in live mode & see if it works. Dell typically adds any new required drivers for kernel, but it can take a release or two before all the updates are in a distribution. I would make sure to back up entire system. You may have a custom grub in ESP that boot an ISO of Dell's 20.04 with any customization. So back up ESP & recovery partition also.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have the backup that I perform periodically and also with Timeshift the entire system. I don't know what the ESP is and if I also have the Recovery partition. I'm not very knowledgeable about all this and maybe I should wait for the Ubuntu and Dell upgrade?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/why-is-no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-from-a-lts-to-the-next)